# Laravel 7 - how to loop a request array to Controller for attaching data with eloquent

Tags: laravel, foreach, eloquent

Please help, so i want to use foreach to loop and attach data to database using Eloquent in my Controller, i passed this is the parsed data as an array :

```
array:3 [▼
  0 => "3"
  1 => "7"
  2 => "9"
]
```

and i want to loop (foreach) and save it to tables using attach() so it can be saved with the same ID in one time like this :

```
Course_ID | Facilitator_Id
--------------------------
1         | 2
1         | 3
1         | 4
--------------------------
```

this is the piece of blade :

```
<form method="POST" action="{{ '/courses' }}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
...
                            <div class="form-group row">
                            <label class="col-3" for="fasil_id">Fasilitator</label>
                            <div class="col-9">
                                <select class="form-control @error('fasil_id') is-invalid @enderror bootstrap-select" data-style="btn-white" multiple name="fasil_id[]" selected="{{ old('fasil_id') }}" required autocomplete="fasil_id">
                                 @foreach($facilitators as $data)
                                  <option value="{{$data->id}}">{{$data->nama}}</option>
                                 @endforeach
                                </select>
                                @error('fasil_id')
                                <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                    <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                </span>
                                @enderror
                            </div>
                        </div>
...
</form>
```

- im using name="fasil_id[]" in the markup properties
- and currently i'm using this method for looping :

  ```
   foreach($request->fasil_id as $fasil_id) {
   Course::find($id)->facilitators()->attach([$fasil_id]); }
  ```

but, sadly i always get this error :

```
htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given
```

Comment: Instead of `->attach([$fasil_id])` use `->attach($fasil_id)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `<select>` opening tag you are setting `selected="{{ old('fasil_id') }}"`.
But since `fasil_id` is an array it cannot be set as the `selected` value and `{{  }}` cannot print it.
Try to remove  `selected="{{ old('fasil_id')`.

As a side note:
You can pass an array to the `attach()` method so you don't need to loop here.
Just do it like this:

```
 Course::find($id)->facilitators()->attach($request->fasil_id);
```

Comment: wow, it really worked! Thank you for your help, i didn't know you can pass an array using attach() without looping, thanks again